# core plot Framework - How to set custom UIView in CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation

Tags: uiview, plot, core-plot

I want to set a custom uiview with label outlets in my graph, if a plot symbol was pressed, using the `scatterPlot:plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:` method.

But how can I give the plot area the UIView or how can I override CPTLayer to draw my custom UIView?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CPTLayer` is a subclass of `CALayer`, so you can't just use the custom `UIView` as a Core Plot annotation. However, you could insert your custom view as a sibling of the Core Plot hosting view (*not* a subview!). Use the plot space to get the coordinates of the touched data point in the plot area and use the built-in `CALayer` methods to convert the coordinates from the plot area layer to the graph layer.

Comment: Ok, I get the right coordinates, but how can I insert my View as a sibling of the hosting view? I tried to add my View to the hostingView but nothing happens.

Comment: I tried something like this:

`CGPoint viewPoint = [plot plotAreaPointOfVisiblePointAtIndex:index];`
`MyCustomView *view = [MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewPoint.x,viewPoint.y,100,100);`
`[self.graph.hostingView addSubview:view];`

Comment: Add your view to the *parent* of the hosting view.