# Coreplot - coordinates and size of axis label

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I use date labels on x axis and want to highlight specific date using custom view. I am planning to use `axis:labelWasSelected:`, move the annotationFrame to labels position and scroll it (move annotation in `plotSpacewillChangePlotRangeToForCoordinate:`) when axis range is changed (simillar to [core plot Framework - How to set custom UIView in CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302288/core-plot-framework-how-to-set-custom-uiview-in-cptplotspaceannotation))

How Can I get coordinates of the label when called from plotSpacewillChangePlotRangeToForCoordinate?

[image]

EDIT:
I have successfully implemented moving annotation invoked by user selection: I save the `_selectedLabel` and send newFrame when range of plot changes. The are 2 problems with that:

1. delay of annotation frame when changing range - see the movie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R66ew6GAiJU&feature=youtu.be
2. when annotated label leaves the screen, the `_selectedLabel` is "forgotten". When moving back to screen probably the new label is created and my `_selectedLabel` references to the old object->frame remains at x=0 (the point it left the screen). Maybe is it somehow possible to get coordinates of specific label (based on comparison with dateToAnnotate)?

   ```
   -(void)axis:(CPTAxis *)axis labelWasSelected:(CPTAxisLabel *)label {
           NSLog(@"labelWasSelected: %@",label);
           _selectedLabel = label;
           CGRect graphLabelFrame = [self adjustAnnotationFrameForLabel:_selectedLabel];
           [_delegate datesPlot:self didAnnotateFrame:graphLabelFrame animating:YES];
       }

   -(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(nonnull CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate {
        CGRect graphLabelFrame = [self adjustAnnotationFrameForLabel:_selectedLabel];
       [_delegate datesPlot:self didAnnotateFrame:graphLabelFrame animating:NO];
   }
   ```

and in Delegate:

```
-(void)datesPlot:(datesPlot*) plot didAnnotateFrame:(CGRect)frame animating:(BOOL)animating{
    if (animating) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        _annotationView.frame = [self.view convertRect:frame fromView:_datesHostingView];
    }];
    }
    else {
        _annotationView.frame = [self.view convertRect:frame fromView:_datesHostingView];
    }

    [_annotationView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

EDIT2:
adjustAnnotation - adds spacing and translates frame to graph coordinates `setNeedLayout` is called by the delegate after it's translated into parent view's coordinates.

```
-(CGRect)adjustAnnotationFrameForSelectedLabel {
    NSLog(@"selected Label:\n %@", _selectedLabel);
    float annotationMargin = 20;
    CGRect labelFrame = _selectedLabel.contentLayer.frame;
    NSLog(@"labelframe: x: %f, y: %f", labelFrame.origin.x, labelFrame.origin.y );
    //add margin for annotation to label's frame
    CGRect annotationFrame  = CGRectMake(labelFrame.origin.x-annotationMargin/2, labelFrame.origin.y-annotationMargin/2,
                                         labelFrame.size.width+annotationMargin, labelFrame.size.height+annotationMargin);
    // convert from plot area coordinates to graph (and hosting view) coordinates
    CGRect graphLabelFrame  = [self.graph convertRect:annotationFrame fromLayer:self.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea];
    NSLog(@"graphLabelFrame: x: %f, y: %f", graphLabelFrame.origin.x, graphLabelFrame.origin.y );
    return graphLabelFrame;

}
```

Comment: check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886928/willchangeplotrangeto-makes-no-difference-to-graphs-in-core-plot

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to the `-axis:labelWasSelected:` method is the axis label. The `contentLayer` of the label is a `CALayer` subclass that actually displays the label. Use the built-in coordinate conversion methods to convert the `frame` and/or `bounds` of the `contentLayer` to the coordinate space of the annotation's `annotationHostLayer`.

Comment: Your solution worked, but I still have some problems. Please, see the edit.

Comment: 1. Does `-adjustAnnotationFrameForLabel:` call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the label layer to make sure its `frame` is up-to-date before reading it?

Comment: 2. The Core Plot labeling policies remove labels when they're no longer visible to save memory. You could use the "none" or "locations provided" policies to have more control over where the labels are. Otherwise, look at the new plot range in the "willChange" delegate method. If the annotation location is outside that range, hide it. If it comes back into the plot range, look at the `tickLocation` of each label to find the one matching the annotation location.

Comment: ad 1. I've added edit2 - setNeedsLayout is called by the delegate (parent view). Calling it in willChangePlotRangeTo or didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate doesn't change anything. Does the labels have appropriate new frame when didChangePlotRangeForCoordinate is called? I observe, that my _selectedLabel's frame is always "one iteration behind" the correct position of the label.

Comment: Core Animation normally takes care of updating the layer layout at a convenient time before each drawing cycle. In this case, you need to read the new `frame` before the automatic layout pass has happened. Before the `CGRect labelFrame = …` statement, call `[_selectedLabel.contentLayer layoutIfNeeded]` to make sure you get the new `frame`.